# Company's view of a recurrent applicant

Tags: hiring-process, applications, pre-screening

After I applied for a position, the employer contacted me to let me know I was  not selected. Weeks later, I saw the same position being offered by the same employer. How would that employer view me if I apply again?

Comment: How much time was in between? Weeks or years? Did anything change on your side, did you gain more experience during that time?

Comment: I would say weeks between the rejection and the repost.

Comment: @Cheluis: In an effort to stop the close votes, I've edited the question to eliminate some unneccessary data, (hopefully) make it easier to understand, and add the information from your comment about how much later this is happening.  If you're unhappy with what I've done, please feel free to [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/13821/edit) the question. From there you can even completely rollback to your previous version if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me it depends on why you were rejected. There are usually 3 reasons you were not selected for the job. Each reason will change my perception of you applying again.

1) You didn't qualify and were not a good candidate.

If this is the case I'll just continue to ignore your repeated applications and may become slightly preturbed. Since I don't want you for the position, then my feelings about you applying again are irrelevant.

2) You qualify and are a great candidate, but there's a better a candidate.

I didn't hire you because someone better came along. In this case I would appreciate you reapplying, so you could be considered for the new position. If I remember you though and you made a good enough impression, I'll probably reach out to you.

3) You're a great candidate but you don't really fit the position I'm looking for.

This is one of those, you're great but you don't really fit here. In this case I may be willing to reconsider you if things have changed on your resume especially in work experience. For the most part though I wouldn't want you to reapply to the exact same position.

That's just my two cents and I'm certain others have different approaches. In the end this specific hiring manager might not agree with any of us. **So I'd recommend contacting him or her directly and asking if it would be ok for you to reapply. This will get you your best answer.**

Comment: thanks for the answer. What if you see the same position reposted? that means that nobody actually get hired. Thanks, I'm very appreciated

Comment: Seeing the same posting can mean several things. It might mean no one was hired, which means they didn't find a suitable candidate, not even one they could settle for. In this case, and this may sound harsh, you're in the group of people they don't think fit in the position. So reapplying would be of no good. It could also mean that their team is expanding and they added that position. In this case reapplying could be a good thing. However, as I said, the best source for this info is the Hiring Manager or equivalent at the company you want to apply for.

Comment: I disagree that reapplying is helpful if the team is expanding.  The company remembers who they interviewed a few weeks ago.  If they like the person, they would reach out and say "we have another position open, are you still interested."  That's a lot more cost effective than starting over.

Comment: If the expansion is happening only a few weeks later then I completely agree with you. But I've been on teams where we hired someone once or twice a year. We don't always remember the previous candidates, plus those candidates may have taken that time and bettered themselves. In that case I'd much rather judge them based on their current skill set then one they presented to me months ago.

Answer (score 3):

> How company would see him if he apply again for it?

In general, if you already been rejected for a particular position, it wouldn't make sense to apply again for the same position. Sometimes though, the position might have the same title, but actually be a different position.

I've seen the same person apply repeatedly for the same position on my team many times.

If I've already rejected the person once, it would be extremely unlikely I'd consider that person a second time for the same position. When I see the same person's resume, I just put it in the "reject" pile.

On the other hand, a person applied for a position on my team. His resume was fairly good, so I called him in for an interview. He didn't actually fit the profile, so I rejected him after the interview.

He later applied for a position with the same title on a different team. That manager hired him.

Comment: "extremely *unlikely*" ?