# Should I apply to the same vacancy I wasn't accepted to if it comes up again in the future?

Tags: interviewing

I went for an interview last December, didn't get the job but I requested feedback and they said I was very close and it just so happened that on that day there was someone else there with more experience specifically in that field.

They said to me to apply again should they have more vacancies.

Now, it's 7 months later, the same vacancy came up again and I am not even invited for an interview this time. What is going on?

Very disappointed to say so at least. There is no point in even asking why, or is there?

So is it ever a good idea to apply again with an organisation you have already applied for and didn't get the job?

Comment: Did you resend your CV when the vacancy came up again? It isn't clear from your question if that is the case.

Comment: Oh I did, they don't do CV's; it's there internal application form and I used that and filled it in all again and added information.

Comment: Relevant [related question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/13821/2322)

Comment: thanks I didnt see that related question. It pretty much answers my question too!

Answer (score 1):

If the vacancy was posted a second time, and you filled in the online form and applied for the new posting, and they didn't call you for interview, then that's that. They don't want you. Complaining will only make things worse, and hurt your chances in the future. However, how do you know they haven't called you for interview, rather than them simply not having got around to setting up interviews yet?

There are a number of reasons why they might not call you for interview. The most likely is that they have a new set of candidates this time round, and they have a number of people much more qualified than you. They might have a candidate in mind, and are only posting the job for the appearance of fairness (yes, it does happen). It's also possible that the second posting is a different job, or in a different department, which has different requirements or just a different hiring manager who just doesn't like your resume as much as the last one. (Yes that can happen, even if the externally posted job description is identical.)

To answer your final question: in general it is absolutely worth it to apply for the same job if it is posted again. There are plenty of other scenarios that would result in you being the best candidate this time round - it just happens that this wasn't one of them.